# Python subprocess can't find Pythonpath module

Tags: python, subprocess, pythonpath

I am trying to use `subprocess.run(['python3.9', "scripts/example.py"], check=True)`.

`example.py` uses a module, that I have added to the PYTHONPATH.
However,
whenever I run the above line, the module is not found.

The confusing part for me is, that printing `sys.path` inside of `example.py` I do see the path to my module.
But when I am running `os.system("which python")` or `os.system("echo $PYTHONPATH")` inside example.py, it returns/prints nothing.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? -- Typically, you would want to use the exact same Python interpreter for the sub-process call, so you would write: `subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'scripts/example.py', check=True)`, unless of course you really do want `python3.9` explicitly and nothing else (which would be surprising). -- And finally, you should check [the doc for the `env` parameter of `subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=env).

Comment: Thank you! using sys.executable and setting the env parameter to a copy of my environment variables where I manually added the pythonpath I needed solved the issue for me.
Thank you so much! This bug took me my whole day to fix :D

Comment: Running Python as a subprocess of Python is often dubious. The simple and elegant solution is to `import` the code you want to run, and not run it in a subprocess at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to check the doc for [the `env` parameter of `subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=env) and set it appropriately.

Side note: typically you would want to use the exact same Python interpreter for the sub-process call, so you would write: `subprocess.run([sys.executable, 'scripts/example.py'], ...)`, unless of course you really do want `'python3.9'` explicitly and nothing else (which would be surprising).